# For loop to convert .lyr files to KML files gives ERROR 000814?

Tags: arcpy, for-loop, error-000814, layer-to-kml

I must convert .lyr files to Kml files. After searching, I already tested 3 codes.
Unfortunately, when running the 3 codes Python displays same error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 4, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2322, in LayerToKML     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000814: Invalid file type

I have no idea how to fix the error.

```
#1
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/ss3/layers"
ou2= r"D:\ss3\kml"
for fc in arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr"):
    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(fc, 'buf_layer')
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management('buf_layer', ou2 + os.path.splitext(fc)[0] + ".kml", "ABSOLUTE")

#2
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/ss3/layers"
ou2= r"D:\ss3\kml"
for fc in arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr"):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, 'buf_layer')
    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion('buf_layer', ou2, "12000", "false", "DEFAULT", "1024", "96", "CLAMPED_TO_GROUND")

#3
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/ss3/polygons"
ou2= r"D:/ss3/layers/"
for fc in arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp"):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, 'buf_layer')
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management('buf_layer', ou2 + os.path.splitext(fc)[0] + ".lyr", "ABSOLUTE")
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/283660/edit) your question and format your code using the `{ }` button.

Comment: Please review previous Q&As here with this error message: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to make a feature layer and save it. You already have the layer files you would like to convert. The extension will be *.kmz* and not *.kml*. The *.kml* lives inside a zipped *.kmz*. You can extract the file and see for yourself. Some further reading from ArcGIS documentation:

> This tool converts a feature or raster layer into a KML file
>   containing a translation of Esri geometries and symbology. This file
>   is compressed using ZIP compression, has a .kmz extension, and can be
>   read by any KML client including ArcGIS Explorer, ArcGlobe, and Google
>   Earth.

The code is commented to explain whats happening.

```python
import arcpy, os

#location of you layers files
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/ss3/polygonslayers"

#location to save kmz files
ou2 = "D:/ss3/kmz/"

#use wildcard to list only files with ".lyr" extension
for layer in arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr"):

    #os.path.splitext: returns a tuple thus: (filename, .extension)
    # on conversion we keep the filename and swap extensions: .lyr for .kmz
    #filename.lyr ==> filename.kmz
    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(layer, ou2 + os.path.splitext(layer)[0] + ".kmz")
```

Comment: I accept the code works as I need.